# Callback is not a function error [Nodejs]

Tags: node.js, callback

I have the following code

```
var getUrl = function(callback) {
  ref.once('value')
    .then(function(snap) {
      let article_url = snap.val();
      console.log(article_url);
      callback(null, article_url); // I dont want to throw an error, so I pass null for the error argument
    });
};

var getImage = function(err, data, callback) {
  //if (err) throw err; // Check for the error and throw if it exists.
  textapi.extract({
    url: data,
    best_image: true
  }, function(error, response) {
    if (error === null) {
      //console.log(response.image);
      if (response.image == null || response.image == "") {
        image = "https://www.wefornews.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/news-3.jpg"
      } else {
        image = response.image;
      }
    }
  });
  callback(null, image); // Otherwise proceed as usual.
};

var updateDatabase = function(err, data) {
  //if (err) throw err; // Check for the error and throw if it exists.
  refupdate.update ({
    "Article_Image_URL": data
  });
  console.log('success'); // Otherwise proceed as usual
};

getUrl(getImage);
getImage(updateDatabase);
```

However I get an error `callback is not a function` at the line `callback(null, image);`

The thing is if I remove the `updateDatabase` function then I get no errors. However when it is within the code I get the error mentioned above. 
Can someone please tell me what can be causing this error?

Comment: any assistance with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `getUrl(getImage)`, the `getImage` function is passed as the `callback` parameter to `getUrl`. `getUrl` then calls this `callback` parameter, passing two parameters.

`callback(null, article_url)`

but `getImage` expects three parameters

`var getImage = function(err, data, callback)`

so `callback` inside the `getImage` function is undefined, and when you try to call undefined as a function

`callback(null, image)`

... you get your `callback is not a function` error.

**Solution**

You need to nest your callbacks so the functions are called in the correct order, with the correct parameters.

```
getUrl(function (err, article_url) {
  getImage(err, article_url, function (err, image) {
    updateDatabase(err, image);
  });
});
```

This could also be simplified since you want to call `updateDatabase` directly after `getImage` completes.

```
getUrl(function (err, article_url) {
  getImage(err, article_url, updateDatabase);
});
```

Also, in your getImage function, the `callback` is called before your `textapi.extract` function completes, which is probably not want you want.

*Before*

```
var getImage = function(err, data, callback) {
  textapi.extract({
    url: data,
    best_image: true
  }, function(error, response) {
    /* code */
  });
  callback(null, image); // This will get called immediately, without waiting for textapi.extract
};
```

*After*

```
var getImage = function(err, data, callback) {
  textapi.extract({
    url: data,
    best_image: true
  }, function(error, response) {
    /* code */
    callback(null, image); // Callback moved here, so it gets called after textapi.extract completes
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const updateDatabase = async (value) => {
  try {
    let snap = await ref.once(value);
    let article_url = snap.val();
    let image = await textapi.extract({
      url: article_url,
      best_image: true
    });
    if (image==='') {image = 'https://www.wefornews.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/news-3.jpg'}
    refupdate.update({
      "Article_Image_URL": article_url
    });
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Comment: that didn't work. What I am trying to do is execute geturl->getImage->updatedatabase. So I am assuming only geturl and getimage should have callbacks.

Comment: indeed, a better option would be to use async/await to avoid callbacks. i'll post another answer

Comment: getting the error `Unexpected token (` for the line `const updateDatabase = async (value)`

Answer (score 0):

because you don't provide any callback on this call `getImage(updateDatabase);` (last line) ?